# How can we say topology on set is collection of open sets?

Tags: general-topology

I have recently started studying topology on my own. Topology $\tau$ on set X is defined as some 3 properties

(1)$\phi, X \in \tau$

(2)Arbitrary union is closed

(3)Finite intersection is closed in $\tau$

But then how can we say that
(1) topology is collection of "open" sets?

(2)for every $x \in X, \exists U_x : x \in U_x, U_x \in \tau$

How to prove (1) and (2)?

Comment: As long as they satisfy the axioms then the elements of $\tau$ are, by definition, open. As for the second question use the first property of a topology to prove this is true.

Comment: For $2$, you can define $U_x=X~\forall x \in X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a topology $\tau$ to be a collection satisfying the three standard axioms. Then you define $O$ to be open iff

$$\forall x \in O: \exists U_x \in \tau: x \in U_x \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

Now the claim is $O$ is open iff $O \in \tau$.

To go from left to right: if $O$ is open according to $(1)$, we have $U_x$ as stated for every $x \in O$ and in fact

$$O = \bigcup\{U_x\mid x \in O\}\tag{2}$$

(to see $\subseteq$ in $(2)$ we just note that every $x \in O$ is in $U_x$, which is a subset of the right hand side by definition, and to see $\supseteq$ we just note that all $U_x$ are subsets of $O$ by definition hence so is their union).
As $(2)$ holds and one of the axioms of $\tau$ is that it is closed under unions and all $U_x$ are in $\tau$, so is $O$. This shows $x$ open according to $(1)$ implies $O \in \tau$.

OTOH, if $O \in \tau$ we can just take $U_x = O$ for every $x \in O$ so $O$ is open according to $(1)$ too.

So by the above, a set is open iff it is in $\tau$. BTW, it's more common to use $(1)$ when we have defined (or are given) a *base* $\mathcal{B}$ for the topology and then we can define open wrt to that base as $(1)$, but choosing $U_x \in \mathcal{B}$ instead. In *that* case there *is* a proof that's needed to show that the thus-defined "open" sets obey the three axioms of $\tau$ and we have indeed defined a proper topology on $X$. Here the axioms on $\tau$ are just given and the observation is boring, but in general you can often define openness from a smaller base collection (which is convenient in many proofs) and don't bother that much with $\tau$ as such.

So in your question you do not have to show $(1)$ and $(2)$, but you're asked to show "$O$ is open by $(1)$ iff $O \in \tau$", which is different.

Comment: thank you sir. I have recently started topology on my own. In Real, i saw meaning of open is some neighborhood(some set containing x) is inside O(set which i want to show that it is open). But here that some neighborhood(open ball) comes from $\tau$. Here i got confused but reading your answer, now it is clear

Comment: @NascimentodeCos the open balls (or open intervals) in $\Bbb R$ are a good example of defining a topology by a base, as I mentioned.

Comment: Sir, one question. If i take discrete topology, each set member is single tonset in $\tau$. Single member is then becoming open set by its inclusion in $\tau$. But then real analysis, i read defination of opn set as neighborhood completel y inside. Similarly cofinite topology on finite set X. Each member is single ton set which is both open and closed.

Comment: It does not look open set to me but is open set and also closed set by defination of topology ...

Comment: @NascimentodeCos In the discrete topology $\tau$ is the power set of $X$ (all subsets). The singletons form a base but not the topology. So I don't quite get your question.

Comment: single ton set is member of power set topology. Since it is include in $\tau$, that single ton set is open set right?

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Yes a singleton is an open set in the discrete topology.

Comment: But in real analysis , set is open if each point neighborhood is completely inside that set. This is not true in case of singleton set in discrete topology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118494/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-nascimento-de-cos).

Answer (score 2):

1. Given a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, a set $V\subseteq X$ is open in $(X,\tau)$ if and only if $V\in\tau$. This is the definition of open and there is nothing to prove.
2. $X\in \tau$ and $\forall x\in X, x\in X$, therefore the property $[\forall x\in X,\exists U_x, (x\in U_x\land U_x\in \tau)]$ is satisfied by $U_x:=X$.

Comment: 1) is just the definition of open sets. Imho, it does not make much sense to characterize it by an iff-statement using literally the definition.

Comment: @Zest I don't understand your point. I didn't make the question and I most certainly didn't decide what topology is. Whether or not it makes sense to you (or to anyone else), the answer to question (1) is what I've written.